# How can I protect my GO REST services in product environment?

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, go, oauth-2.0

I'm recently dealing with Go REST services, but I don't know if there any production-ready OAUTH2 server available?

As my services will be consumed by a single-paged web app as well as mobile clients, and users should be able to register their accounts, so I'm thinking about an OAUTH2 server.

I've been searching around and found that the standard package contains only the client side code https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go.

There is an OAUTH2 server built in Go (https://github.com/RangelReale/osin), but I don't have much expertise to review it.

Therefore, what are the options available for production applications? Should I use an OAUTH server implemented in another technology like nodejs because of their maturity?

EDIT: In .Net space there is a server implementation at https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3

However, I would prefer something in GO.

Comment: Are you talking about normal user access or the oauth access scenario?

Comment: HI inf, I'm talking about both of them. The service must authenticate and authorize normal users. Potentially support mobile applications developed by third-party companies. In .Net space there is an OAUTH2 implementation https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after I asked the question, CoreOS released "dex" as an open source OpenID provider at https://github.com/coreos/dex

Answer (score 0):

Though Oauth2 is very secure and a great implementation.

A common procedure used to secure web applications is as follows.

User registers to application and sends registration data to backend.
Server handles registration information.
Store hashed user password for future token requests and other such requests
Create access token to be passed back to user(usually 32-64 bit)
hash access token and store it in database for authentication of restful requests
Send user back any data required as well as access token.
Store access token on client machine(Possibly using localstorage.set() )
Future requests will have the access token attached to them for authentication.

Always check that the access token is still access and that it's hash matches the hashed value in the database.

Other implementations involve JWT's and so on.

Comment: OAuth2 is only as secure as the implementation: HTTPS only, correct validating and expiring tokens, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have enough expertise in reviewing OAuth 2.0 library, then I would recommend to use reliable third party Oauth-as-a-service provider.

One example I know is Microsoft Azure ACS, which you can integrate with your golang application, and they will handle OAuth process as well as authentication and authorisation for you.

You can read about how it works [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx).